# Possibility to create a log file of activities on a Google Home?

Tags: android, logging, google-home, google-assist-api

I am currently working on this project where I need some kind of log file that stores all of the activities that a user has invoked on a Google Home device. Anyone who has an idea how to do this? I doubt if it is possible since Google is kind of limiting when it comes to Google Home development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to get the Google activity list.

Google provides this to users directly at https://myactivity.google.com/